# Change default cargo dependency location

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In rust, package manager Cargo, by default fetches the dependency packages like futures or tokio and places at

> /home/.cargo/bin
> , > /home/.cargo/git , > /home/manjaro/.rustup/

. Can user configure different path to fetch rust libraries and get linked during cargo build ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `CARGO_HOME` environmental variable.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/cargo-home.html

There is also an option to set the `target` directory location: `CARGO_TARGET_DIR`, https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildtarget-dir
Some people set it to a global target folder to reduce used disk space if they have multiple projects with similar dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Is RUSTUP_HOME environment variable to customize the rustup downloads ?

Comment: yes, see https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/environment-variables.html